# Prove $\exists \xi, \eta \in (0,1)$, such that $f(\xi)+f'(\eta)=\xi+\eta$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Suppose $f(x)$ is continuous in $[0,1]$,  derivable in $(0,1)$, $f(0)=0, f(1)=\frac 12$, prove 
>   $\exists \xi, \eta \in (0,1)$, such that
>   $$
>  f(\xi)+f'(\eta)=\xi+\eta.
> $$

I have tried Cauchy mean value theorem:

let $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)-t \,dt, G(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2-f(x)$, then $\exists \xi \in (0,1), \eta \in (0,1)$, such that

$$
\frac{F(1)-F(0)}{1-0} = F'(\xi) 
\Leftrightarrow f(\xi)-\xi = \int_0^1 f(t) \,dt - \frac 12.
$$
$$
\frac{G(1)-G(0)}{1-0} = G'(\eta) 
\Leftrightarrow \eta-f'(\eta) = \frac 12 - f(1) = 0.
$$

but failed.

Any hints are appreciated, thanks for your help.

---

The conditions of this question are wrong, but if i rectify them, the question will contradict the anwser of Mr. Robert  Z to some extent, so please be sure to see the anwser after skimming this question. I am sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: It feels like a place where we want to use [Rolle's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem) somehow...

Comment: @gcfsjfcus Do you mind to write something about the origin of this problem? I am curious about it!

Comment: @RobertZ This is a postgraduate examination question of the Chinese Academy of Sciences.

Comment: @RobertZ May be recalled by candidates.

Comment: @gcfsjfcus Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The statement is false, I have a counterexample: if $f(x)=x^2/2$ then $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=\frac 12$, and
$$f(\xi)+f'(\eta)=\frac{\xi^2}{2}+\eta<\xi+\eta$$
for any $\xi,\eta\in(0,1)$.

Note that the proposition holds with $\xi\in [0,1)$ and $\eta\in(0,1)$. In fact, let $F(x)=f(x)-x^2/2$ then $F(0)=F(1)=0$ and therefore, by Rolle's theorem, there is $\eta\in(0,1)$ such that $F'(\eta)=f'(\eta)-\eta=0$. Then by letting $\xi=0$ we get
$$f(\xi)+f'(\eta)=\xi+\eta.$$

Comment: Nice. Is it true that there is always $\eta, \xi \in [0,1]$ that does the job?

Comment: @Mason Yes, see my edit.

Comment: @RobertZ many thanks!

Comment: @RobertZ [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1927339/existence-of-xi-and-eta-such-that-f-xif-eta-xi-eta),the question is correct?How to prove?

Comment: @RobertZ $f'(\xi)+f'(\eta)=\xi+\eta$ is wrong?I think this is correct.

Comment: @RobertZ $f'(x)$ should be $x$?

Comment: @梦里年华似烟花 I think I got it now!

Comment: @RobertZ We do it by the same way.You figure it out sooner

Comment: @RobertZ I ask a similar question which also has two-parameter, could you please try to solve it？Thanks.

Comment: @梦里年华似烟花 Where is your question?

Comment: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3117494/prove-fracf-xig-xi-fracf-etag-eta-0)